# Do any open source Linux terminals and fonts support ligatures?

Tags: terminal, fonts, terminal-emulator

The [PragmataPro Font](http://www.fsd.it/shop/fonts/pragmatapro) has some really killer examples where they render `==` as a single character and clean up a lot of other stuff.

[image: Example of PragmataPro]

Would any Linux terminals support this? And are there any alternatives to PragmataPro?

Comment: You might find the discussion at this `gnome-terminal` feature request useful: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=762832

Comment: It is [packaged in the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-pragmatapro/): that seems to answer all your questions... And there is no source, it is a font, but it is licensed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

So there are a few open source fonts targeting programmers that support ligatures, namely

- [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode)
- [Hasklig](https://github.com/i-tu/Hasklig)
- [Monoid](http://larsenwork.com/monoid/)
- [Iosevka](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka)
- [CascadiaCode](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code)

However, very few opensource terminals that run natively on Linux yet support this. But you can find an current list in the [FiraCode docs](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#terminal-compatibility-list)

- [Kitty](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty) **I am using Kitty on `i3` and I really love it**
- [Black Screen](https://github.com/shockone/black-screen) (slow in browser terminal emulator that runs on node)
- [Konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/) (terminal editor that uses Qt)
- [QTerminal](https://github.com/lxde/qterminal) (terminal editor that uses Qt)

## No support

- [Alacritty](https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty/issues/50)

Comment: I did read somewhere that vte terminals doesn't support ligatures. Why that?

Comment: Would these terminals also support things like sparkline fonts like: https://github.com/aftertheflood/sparks or https://github.com/figs-lab/datalegreya

Comment: PragmataPro is designed to be beautiful without antialiasing, it's a shame that antialiasing cannot be disabled in Kitty :/

Comment: wezterm also support ligatures and is gpu accelerated: https://github.com/wez/wezterm